# Java read and save GUI elements

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, element

I have a question regarding accessing GUI elements. For example having a simple GUI program on Java, how can I read and save the Swing GUI elements hierarchy on a tree (ex. including main window, frames, button, textfield, combobox etc.).

Comment: Are you talking about accessing the hierarchy or serializing it to disk and then reconstituting it later?

Comment: Firstly I need to access this hierarchy and later I might need also to serialize since I will have to implement other stuff such that it need to use EventDispatcher in order to relate (map) in runtime UI elements to specific events inside code. This is my goal, so is it possible?

Comment: Its not very clear what you're getting at. Its quite simple to map events on the gui to call specific bits of code for example.

Comment: @Bill How to access the tree hierarchy? I need the whole tree of UI elements.

Answer (score 4):

Swing applications are already organized in trees. The JFrame is the root, children can be visited by:

```
Component[] components1 = mFrame.getContentPane().getComponents();
```

Every components has sub-components that you can get by:

```
// Assuming component is a container
((Container)component).getComponents();
```

Saving these elements into a file is an easy operation. Here is a good [article](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue013a.html) to get you strated.

**EDIT** The beauty of streams is that you can use a file just as you would use a socket :) 
Thus turning [ComponentSerializer](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue013a.html) component to serialize into a file instead of a socket requires 0 changes :)

Say your have a JFrame you want to save/read to/from a file, you do the following:

```
OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("FileName.bin");
JFrame myFrame = new JFrame();
ComponentSerializer serializer = new ComponentSerializer();
serializer.write(myFrame, output);

// Reading from file
InputStream in = new FileInputStream("FileName.bin");
ComponentSerializer serializer = new ComponentSerializer();
JFrame myFrame = (JFrame) serializer.read(in);
myFrame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Also consider `XMLEncoder`/`XMLDecoder` as an alternative to `Serializable`.

Comment: @GETah: Can you provide a simple (full) example how this with components and sub-components can be done? I was thinking whether there is a more automated and dynamic capturing of these GUI components (whole tree), since this seems manually!

Comment: The article I posted at the end of the answer contains a fully working example that serializes GUI components and sends them though the network. You can use the same mechanism to save your stuff to disk instead

Comment: I was assuming there is more dynamic and automated way of capturing these GUI elements using JVM . Do you know anything about this?

Comment: Huuum I would be surprised if it does exist in the JVM. GUI's are not meant to be serialized, their state however is. This is being said, you can still use the algorithm mentioned in the article and serialize any kind of GUI.

Comment: I found difficult to adapt the example in the article. I would appreciate if you could provide me with solution instead of sending through network, just save them in a memory file or even a data structure! 
Thank you!

Comment: @GETah Thank you for your posts. Do you know how to write the whole GUI elements hierarchy as a tree into file? You mentioned at the very beginning that SWING elements are already listed in a tree, so how can I access the whole tree and write it into file?

Comment: @100798 If you want to serialize and save the whole GUI then all what you have to do is to serialize the main frame content pane, no need to figure out the tree. That will save all other contained components automatically :)

Comment: @GETah By this following your modified (extended) example with input and output streams, serializing only the main JFrame (ex.myFrame) will save other components as well (ex. buttons, textfields ect)?

The second part :

JFrame myFrame = serializer.read(in);

Has an error. It says, cannot convert from component to JFrame!?
It should show the serialized JFrame again, is it? 

Sorry for making so much questions, but I really need to find a solution for my problem!
Thank you!

Comment: @100798 Don't be sorry, we are all here to learn :) My bad, I forgot casting the component to JFrame. Please see my code updates. Also please mark this as an answer if it resolves all your issues :)

Comment: @GETah I tried what you suggested and that's OK. But instead of having the complete content of UI objects (copy) with serialization, do you know how I can only have the tree of these objects without their complete content (properties, parameters ect.). Example: Main windows (frame), then each panel, each panel's elements (button, textfield) ect. There should a simple solution how only to have references of these UI elements without their whole content).

Comment: @100798 Good that it worked. Please mark this as an answer and post a new question with your new requirements :)